# How to call another function within events of fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to call another function , **fetchData()** , within my ***eventReceive*** function, but I keep getting ***fetchData() is not defined*** or ***_this.fetchData() is not function***

```
<FullCalendar
        defaultView="dayGridMonth"
        header={{
          left: "prev,next today",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
        }}
        editable={true}
        droppable={true}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        events={testSubtask[0] ? testSubtask[0].map(d => ({

               "id": d.id,
               "title": d.name,
               "start": d.start,
               "end": d.end
               })) : null}
        eventReceive={function (info ) {
            this.fetchDraggingTask();  //HOW TO CALL DIFFERENT FUNCTION HERE?  

        }}
 />
```

Comment: Please stop spam-tagging all the fullCalendar tags. Just add the ones which are actually related to your implementation. I had to remove them on your previous post as well.

Comment: Anyway it's hard to know if you are calling your fetchData() function correctly or not, because we can't see how or where you've defined it. Give us enough information to reproduce the problem, please.

Comment: @ADyson the function is simply to console.log the info of eventReceive . I want to do simple function first, but the function is not detected..

Comment: Whether it's simple or not isn't the issue. We need to see how/where it's defined in order to understand why it would appear not to be in scope. Provide enough code to reproduce your error please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is the official guidance on creating usable code examples when asking a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working around with fullcalendar lately. I think this way might work out.

```
<FullCalendar
    defaultView="dayGridMonth"
    header={{
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
    }}
    editable={true}
    droppable={true}
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
    events={testSubtask[0] ? testSubtask[0].map(d => ({

           "id": d.id,
           "title": d.name,
           "start": d.start,
           "end": d.end
           })) : null}
    eventReceive={(info) => this.fetchDraggingTask(info)}
 />
```